# Creating user defined immutable objects

Tags: d

```
  immutable auto a = Array!int([1, 2, 3]);
```

> Error: cannot implicitly convert expression (((Array!int __slArray2557 = Array(RefCounted(RefCountedStore(null)));) , __slArray2557).this([1, 2, 3])) of type Array!int to immutable(Array!int)

Often I just want to create some object at runtime, initialize it and then make it immutable but if I try to do this, I get the error from above.

It seems that I can cast a mutable object to an immutable object

```
  immutable auto a = cast(immutable Array!int) Array!int([1, 2, 3]);
```

Why do I have to cast it to `immutable`?

Is casting to immutable even legal?

Comment: I know actually almost nothing about D, but if you declare a variable as immutable, the compiler will probably expect that the right-hand side expression is an immutable object, so of course if that's not case, it will probably give you an error. Regarding if it's legal or not, I don't know, but if you don't receive an answer, I recommend you to ask this same question on one of the D forums in the official website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `Array` is reference counted, it isn't compatible with immutable right now - it keeps a pointer to a reference count inside it which cannot change if it is immutable, breaking the whole thing. The cast just bypasses the rules, which compiles but is undefined behavior.

If it is immutable, just ditch the `Array` wrapper and use an ordinary slice:

```
// this works fine
immutable a = [1, 2, 3];
```

(heck, the Array wrapper is basically useless if you pass it a literal anyway, since the ordinary array is constructed just to pass to its constructor, where it gets constructed again!)

BTW the `auto` in `immutable auto` is unnecessary, you can just call it `immutable`.

You could also make a mutable array of immutable data, that should work too - it just needs mutability because of its memory management scheme.

Comment: Is there some documentation about what can be immutable? It seems that when I create a custom type containing a pointer or slice it can't be immutable. I guess what I really wanted was probably just const.

Comment: const wouldn't work with reference counting either. But in general, if you want to know whether a type works with const or immutable, start by looking at its member functions and seeing which ones are const, immutable, or inout. Functions that don't have any of them definitely won't work with `const` or `immutable`. If enough of them are marked with those attributes, then it will likely work, though if the documentation doesn't say, and you're not dealing with a fairly simple type, there's a good chance that `immutable` won't work. Another good clue is if it can be constructed as immutable.

Comment: I think this is the newest article on immutable: http://dlang.org/spec/const3.html but basically the rule is just that once you enter const/immutable land, you never leave it. So if the outer layer is immutable, so are all the members, and all the data pointed to by the members, and so on. An immutable variable cannot be modified by anything - including internal pointer resizing and freeing, also including struct assignments. Only time it can be freed is when there are no more references, so the program never knows it was all just an illusion (hence the GC can free it, but you can't.)